# Is Python dict an Object?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dict` like this:

```
>>> my_dict = {u'2008': 6.57, u'2009': 4.89, u'2011': 7.74,
...            u'2010': 7.44, u'2012': 7.44}
```

Output with `has_key`:

```
>>> my_dict.has_key(unicode(2012))
True
```

Output with `hasattr`:

```
>>> hasattr(my_dict, unicode(2012))
False
```

I couldn't understand why this behaves differently. 
I googled and found out that it is because `dict` and objects are different.

But, still I couldn't understand the difference properly.

(BTW : I am using python 2.7)

Comment: By the way: `has_key` is *deprecated* and was removed in python3. Use `the_key in the_dictionary` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`dict` instances are objects too. But their keys are just not exposed as as attributes.

Exposing the keys as attributes (too or instead of item access) would lead to namespace pollution; you'd never be able to use a `has_key` key, for example. `has_key` is *already* an attribute on dictionaries:

```
>>> hasattr({}, 'has_key')
True
>>> {}.has_key
<built-in method has_key of dict object at 0x7fa2a8461940>
```

Attributes of objects and the contents of dictionaries are two *separate* things, and the separation is deliberate.

You can always subclass `dict` to add attribute access using the [`__getattr__()` hook method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return self[name]
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

Demo:

```
>>> demo = AttributeDict({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> demo.keys()
['foo']
>>> demo.foo
'bar'
```

*Existing* attributes on the `dict` class take priority:

```
>>> demo['has_key'] = 'monty'
>>> demo.has_key
<built-in method has_key of AttributeDict object at 0x7fa2a8464130>
```

Comment: You're too fast for me :-/ I wanted to write a similar answer, but then I saw "3 new answers"...

Comment: @moose: On weekends the balance between question askers and answerers appears to be skewed a little towards answerers.. :-)

Comment: Thank you @martijn-pieters, really nice explanation, I couldn't understand about the namespace pollution, can you please explain that to me?

Comment: @JohnPrawyn: the attributes on an object are a namespace; `dct.keys()`, `dct.items()`, etc. If dictionary contents were also attributes, they pollute that namespace; you start mixing extra names into it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters really cool, but when we subclass a dict to add attribute access using the __getattr__() hook method, are we not polluting the namespace?

Comment: @JohnPrawyn: You are :-) I was offering it as a work-around, in case you *really* wanted to have attribute access to the contents *anyway*. Using the `__getattr__` hook does mean that existing attributes on the dictionary come first. Any keys that match existing attributes are thus masked and not accessible as attributes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks a lot, for the answer and your patience and towards me.

Answer (score 3):

`has_key` checks for the existence of a key in the dictionary. (One your code defines while creating a dictionary) [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) checks if the object has an attribute.

Dictionaries are objects, and they have certain attributes. `hasattr` checks for those.

```
>>> hasattr(dict, 'has_key')
True
>>> hasattr(dict, 'items')
True
>>> newDict = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> newDict.has_key('a')
True
```

You can use [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) which lists out the valid attributes for an object.

```
>>> dir(dict)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_dict.has_key(unicode(2012))`: `has_key` looks for a key in a dictionary. Keys in a dictionary are not attributes and

> ***hasattr(object, name)***
>
> The arguments are an object and a string. The
>   result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s
>   attributes, False if not. (This is implemented by calling
>   getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an exception or
>   not.)

from which you can see that, although dict are objects, dict's keys are not the dict's attributes;

Answer (score 1):

Dict is an object, as anything in Python is an object. There's, however, a difference between an objects attribute and a dicts key.
The dict doesn't store its keys as attributes!
The only way to access a dicts keys is through the `__getitem__` method or the `[]` operator.

If you want to access the items this way, you can override the `__getattr__` method and make it return the `__getitem__` result in stead.

You can also create something like this:

```
   class ObjectDict(dict):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
           super(ObjectDict, self).__init__(*args, **kws)
           self.__dict__ = self
```

Which will result in this behavior:

```
>>> d = ObjectDict()
>>> d['a'] = 3
>>> d.a
3
>>> hasattr(d, 'a')
True
```

But this is known to cause memory leaks in Python

Answer (score 0):

`attribute` returns some property of an instance so that you can manipulate it.
Now understand `attribute` will always return something, but if a `key` is not in `d`, `d[key]` will raise `KeyError`.

`hasattr` checks if an `instantce` has that `attribute` or not. Since `dictionary` `keys` are no `attribute` to the `dictionary` it returns `False`.

example :

```
# python3
>>> d = {1:True}
>>> dir(d) # this shows all the attributes of the instance
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__'
, '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '_
_new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__'
, '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get
', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
>>> hasattr(d,'keys')
True
>>> 1 in d.keys()
True
```

Comment: *attribute means class method or constant*. No, attribute means attribute. Functions are attributes, coupled with the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) makes them return as methods. Properties are attributes and descriptors. You can store functions on instances as attributes, they are then callable too but not methods. Etc. There are no constants in Python.

Comment: no i meant class constant. sorry I wrote it wrong. What I meant, attribute means, something which does some kind of operation on an object and return some another object. whereas, dict keys are totally different. I might be wrong, tell me more or give me some link.

Comment: The canonical reference is the [Python datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).