# getattr lookup fails for instance of class python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, getattr

I'm doing an exercise in which you're supposed to calculate a score of how classy your items are. A tophat gives you 2 points, a bowtie gives you 4 points and a monocle gives you 5 points. I've initiated a dictionary with these items on each class instance, yet when I use `getattr` to check if the item has the attribute it always returns `None`.

```
class Classy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.classyItems = {'tophat': 2, 'bowtie': 4, 'monocle': 5}

    def addItem(self, str):
      self.items.append(str)

    def getClassiness(self):
      classiness = 0
      for item in self.items:
        itemIsClassy = getattr(self.classyItems, item, None) # Why does this always return none?
        if itemIsClassy:
          classiness += itemIsClassy
        else:
          pass
      return classiness


# Test cases
me = Classy()

# Should be 0
print me.getClassiness()

me.addItem("tophat")
# Should be 2
print me.getClassiness() # I'm getting 0
```

Why is `getattr` returning `None` when `self.classyItems` clearly has the attribute of tophat?

Thanks for the help everyone! I was still confused after reading the answer and simply reading that dictionary keys are not attributes here helped me. [Is Python dict an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761202/is-python-dict-an-object)

Comment: You can use dict default value `self.classyItems.get(item, None)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getattr` accesses attributes and/or methods, but `classyItems` is a dict which doesn't have any (visible) attributes<sup>1</sup> and stores its contents as key-value pairs<sup>2</sup>.

In your case you should use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead of `getattr`, more specifically `self.classyItems.get(item, None)`, to access the values with default.

<sup>1</sup>Dictionaries have methods that could be accessed using `getattr` though.

<sup>2</sup>That's why you access them using `d[key]` instead of `d.key`.

Answer (score 2):

`getattr()` takes an **object** and a **string** of the **attribute** to look for, and returns **that object**. You don't have an attribute named `item` in your object, but you do have `classyItems`:
Using your code you can see that:

```
>>> getattr(me, 'classyItems')
{'bowtie': 4, 'tophat': 2, 'monocle': 5}
```

It is much easier (and readable) to use `self.classyItems.get(item, None)` which looks up a dict and returns default value. You can't lookup a dict values with `getattr`, but you can however check if it has certain methods:

```
>>> getattr(me.classyItems, 'update')
<built-in method update of dict object at 0x028ADE40>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `itemIsClassy = getattr(self.classyItems, item, None)` to `itemIsClassy = self.classyItems.get(item, None)`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @Dharmesh and @MSeifert, replace `itemIsClassy = getattr(self.classyItems, item, None)` to `itemIsClassy = self.classyItems.get(item, None)`

The reason why your code didn't work is not because `classyItems` doesn't have many attributes, it is because the `getattr` function works on objects, not dictionary.