# What is the difference between bunch and dictionary type in python?

Tags: python

I found out that `sklearn.utils.Bunch` and `dict` work more or less the same. Like if there is a `dict` object say

```
dict_1 = {"a":1, "b":2}
```

and a bunch object say bunch

```
bunch_1 = Bunch(a=1, b=2)
```

both have the same set of behaviour.

Comment: Since this isn’t a standard built in class, you should really clarify where this comes from.

Comment: from sklearn module, the object returned by datasets.load_iris() was of type Bunch

Comment: I won’t recommend using Bunch, since this project is not maintained any longer (last released in dec. 2011). See also https://github.com/dsc/bunch/issues

Comment: is there anything that is similar to bunch? where i can get attribute style access to dict values?

Comment: @fireblaze The distinction exists explicitly, so you can store data in `d['keys']` and use methods of the dict as `d.keys()`, otherwise this would be a naming clash. Even if most of the time you may not encounter this, it’s a fundamental problem classes like `Bunch` need to deal with.

Comment: @Abhilash Prakash Python hide/abandon dict's key as attribute, plz see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761202/is-python-dict-an-object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bunch is a subclass of the Dict class and supports all the methods as dict does. In addition, it allows you to use the keys as attributes.

```
b = Bunch(a=1, b=2)
>>> b['b']
2
>>> b.b
2
```

[Read more here](https://pypi.org/project/bunch/)

Comment: So, a [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=simplenamespace#types.SimpleNamespace)

Answer (score 2):

Bunch is just like dictionary but it supports attribute type access.

1. **Data Type**

- Dictionary is in-built type, whereas Bunch is from bunchclass
  package.  bunchclass.
- Bunch works fine in python 2, but in python 3
  it does not work! You import Bunch from sklearn.utils

  `from bunchclass import Bunch`    # python 2

  `from sklearn.utils import Bunch` # python 3

2. **Initialization**
   Initialization of bunch does not require `{}`, but an explicit function with attributes of the elements you required to be in the bunch.

   ```
   d1 = {'a':1, 'b':'one', 'c':[1,2,3], 4:'d'}`
   b1 = Bunch(a=1, b='one', c=[1,2,3])    # Also note: here the keys of Bunch are
                                          # attributes of the class. They must be
                                          # mutable and also follow the
                                          # conventions for variables.
   ```
3. **Accessing the value of the key**
   This is the main difference between the two.

   ```
   d1['a']
   b1['a']
   b1.a
   ```

In a `Bunch`, you can access the attributes using dot notations. In a `dict` this is not possible.

**Similarities**
Both Dictionary and bunch can contain values of any data type. But keys must be mutable.
There can be nested dictionaries and nested bunches.

**Utilities of Bunch**

- Bunch() is useful serialization to json.
- Bunch() is used to load data in sklearn. Here normally a bunch contains various attributes of various types(list, numpy array, etc.,).

**More on Bunch**
as with any other object use `dir(Bunch object)` to know more.
Refer to this link to know more about bunch:[Bunch](https://github.com/dsc/bunch)

In case your aim is to convert a bunch into dataframe, you can refer this link https://github.com/viswanathanc/basic_python/blob/master/sklearn.utils.bunch%20to%20pandas%20Dataframe.ipynb