# how to display/view `sklearn.utils.Bunch` data set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, databricks

I am going through a tutorial that uses `sklearn.utils.Bunch` as a data set:

`cal_housing = fetch_california_housing()`

I'm running this on a Databricks notebook.

I've read through the documentation that I can find like
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.Bunch.html and search engines aren't yielding anything useful.

but how can I see/view what's in this data set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can convert it to pandas dataframe:

```
df = california_housing.fetch_california_housing()
calf_hous_df = pd.DataFrame(data= df.data, columns=df.feature_names)    
calf_hous_df.sample(4)
```

[image]

Moreover, you can see attributes:

```
df.keys()
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'feature_names', 'DESCR'])
```

Comment: But what is a bunch? Is it just a dictionary? Is it a stream or pipeline connected to a csv file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58788714/13726668. Just a dict with extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

the `sklearn.utils.Bunch` data can be viewed by using `pandas` to make it into a dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(cal_housing.data,columns=cal_housing.feature_names)
data
```